# How do I grab input value and it's relvant table heading/row title to store as a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mongodb

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r55t5o2m/

I have a 3 part cart that allows customers to select how many rooms they want cleaned and calculate the total price. However I'd like to have the customer submit the results and have it stored in a Json format so the site owner can retrieve the results from a database(MongoDB)....not just the final total value.

I tried this [Jquery plug-in table-to-json](http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/) but it returns only all availible select options not the currently held index value selected.

For example, using this code below on my main site results in this:

```
$('#carpetclean').change( function() {
  var table = $('#carpetclean').tableToJSON(); // Convert the table into a javascript object
  console.log(table);
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));
});
```

returns:

```
[{"":"Room(s)","Clean":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Protect":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Deodorize":"Free!"},{"":"Staircase(s)","Clean":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Protect":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Deodorize":"Free!"},{"":"Bath/Laundry(s)","Clean":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Protect":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Deodorize":"Free!"},{"":"Hallway(s)","Clean":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Protect":"0\n  1\n  2\n  3\n   4\n  5\n  6\n  7\n   8\n  9","Deodorize":"Free!"}]
```

instead I'd just need the current index value of the select/option for each relevant role.

Any advice on the best way to proceed?

Comment: Are you open to using a different storage and retrieval setup?

Comment: Are you using .change() for the results to be displayed somewhere as the user selects info?  If not, why not just iterate through all the values once on submit?

Comment: @fauxserious, check the fiddle. that last bit of code is just to see the output of the plug-in for table-to-json. I need a way to grab the current selected value, not just the raw output of the table. I'm using drop down selectors.

Comment: @Delight, yeah, MySQL is an option